# How to add a list of a dialog box and link it to a button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I am new to android development and I was wondering how can I link a dialog box (with a list of options inside it) and the dialog should open when a press a button on the UI

The code I have written so far:

```
package awad865.project.ContactManager1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class OptionActivity extends Activity {

    private Button button1;
    private Button button2;
    private Button button3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_option);
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);


        button1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button_sort);

        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(OptionActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Sort list by?");


            }
        });
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.option, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: You can add a textview, make it invisible, then make an onclicklistener for the button, then make the textview visable via the onclicklistener.

Comment: You should probably have a [read here first](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AddingAList) and then come back with more specific questions if you run into any problems. The documentation is rather extensive, so you'll probably do fine. Once you get a basic dialog showing, be sure to read up how to wrap it in `DialogFragment`. You'll see why if you change the device orientation when not using one (or the deprecated `showDialog()`/`dismissDialog()` methods).

Comment: I did have a look at the android developer website. I am not sure how to link in the dialog box with the button

Answer (score 0):

You need to have custom view for the Dialog with the list of options. you can either go for Alertdialog or DialogFragments.

Check [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.au/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html)  sample code on how to use DialogFragments.

If you are using `AlertDialog` check this [sample](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/)

Comment: Custom view? Why? Doesn't an `AlertDialog` have built-in functionality to [display a list](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AddingAList)? Also, `AlertDialog` and `DialogFragment` aren't two exclusive building blocks. As a matter of fact: they go hand in hand. Generally, you'll want to use an `AlertDialog` *inside* a `DialogFragment`.

Comment: @MH. Thanks for the link. Thats something new to me. Appreciate it. Please answer this question. Will remove my answer as it doesnt suggest the correct one!